# Having trouble seperating all the integers from the list

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble separating all the integers and strings with integers from a list. Not only this but I don't want the integers to repeat.
If you look at the code below, it does this, however, when it encounters integers within a string, i.e.;, '1', '713', it considers these values purely a string and not integer.

```
 def filter_lis(txt):
       all_num = []
       for i in txt:
            if i not in all_num and type(i) == int:
               all_num.append(i)
       return all_num


sentence_list = [45, 45, 45, 10, 1, 2, 7, 'abc', 'd', '713']

print(filter_lis(sentence_list))
```

What are my options here? I know of the isinstance() and type() string methods, but niether of these seem to give me what I want.

Edit**

When I run this code this is my output:

```
[45, 10, 1, 2, 7]
```

As you can see, it missed the '713'.

Comment: What is your actual output and what is your desired output? Also, `'713'` *is* a string so testing for str vs. int is not the right solution.

Comment: Seems you want to convert strings to numbers. Then consider whether it should convert scientific notation, fractions, binary or hexadecimal literals, etc.

Comment: You can use `i.isnumeric()` to test if it's a string that contains a number.

Comment: @jarmod My desired output is to have all integers from a list provided, appended to a new list, all_num. I have edited my original question and included the output I am getting

Comment: @Barmar the problem with isnumeric() is that when it iterates over an integer, it produces an error

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need something like this, if I got you right :

```
def filter_lis(lst):
    tmp = list(set(lst));r = []   #remove the duplicates,return to list for easier handling
                                  # r - list of indxs to remove
    for num, i in enumerate(tmp):
        if not isinstance(i, int):
            try:tmp[num] = int(i)
            except: r.append(num)
    tmp = [i for num, i in enumerate(tmp) if num not in r]
    return tmp

sentence_list = [45, 45, 45, 10, 1, 2, 7, 'abc', 'd', '713', '413',"aaaa", "blaa"]
print(filter_lis(sentence_list))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 7, 10, 45, 413, 713]
```